# O meu design no Android Studio

Tags: android-xml

o design do meu app não está aparecendo não sei por que ? alguem pode me ajudar[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1GoB.png)

Comment: Você poderia incrementar sua pergunta informando o XML da activity, isso melhoraria a qualidade da pergunta e possibilitaria a identificação do problema.

Comment: bom eu ja conseguir descobrir o por que de não esta aparecendo, era uma opção que tinha que selecionar no menu, e muito obrigado por responder a minha pergunta!